# EU cookie law solutions, opinions & experiences

Tags: cookie, google-analytics

The EU cookie law requires that many Magento websites will need an update to avoid fines. So far I have only seen extensions that have an accept-button and occasionally a deny-button, which leads the visitor away from the website. These options do not seem compliant with the EU cookie law and they also do not promote more sales.

Is there a good (generic) solution for the EU cookie law for Magento? If not, is it feasible to develop a generic solution for this?

Does anyone have any experience, solutions, opinions, etc. on this subject? It would be nice to have this page as a detailed guide to working with EU cookie law.

Answer (score 2):

Magento respects the EU cookie law by a new feature introduced in Magento CE 1.7 and Magento EE 1.12.

You can activate the "Cookie Restriction Mode" by enabling this option in "System" > "Configuration" > "General" > "Web" > "Session Cookie Management".

The CMS page "Privacy Policy" (URL key "privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode") is used to inform the customers about what gets stored, how the data is used etc.

Comment: I don't believe this is sufficient. Countries like Bulgaria, Denmark, Lithuania and The Netherlands demand clear and comprehensive information about the cookies that are set upon visiting the site.

Comment: At first sight, the information seems quite detailed (scroll to the bottom of the page for information on several parts of the cookie being stored). I'd say that a part of the information that has to be declared also depends on what the shop owner really is doing with the data. I'd like to learn where the default information is missing. Do you have some resources that I could have a look at?

Comment: Here are some (somewhat conflicting) documents:
* http://www.ffw.com/pdf/cookie-consent-tracking-table.pdf
* http://ddma.nl/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2012/06/DDMA-Europese-Cookie-implementation-table-June-2012.pdf

I believe that the Dutch implementation of the EU cookie law requires detailed information about used cookies on the page of the pop-up (or whatever is used).

Comment: Not only does it require that you inform the user about all the cookies that are going to be set, you must give the user the possibility of opting-out. 

This is true for all but 'functional' cookies - cookies that you need to provide functionality like shopping-carts and session.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly there has been a development on the EU cookie regulations in the UK in that the ICO has today announced they themselves will be implementing implied consent from the end of the month. http://www.ico.gov.uk/news/current_topics/changes-to-cookies-on-our-website.aspx

I know that doesn't necessarily help those in other EU countries but the information is useful anyway.